# Why implicit parameters cannot be passed explicitly when they undergo an implicit conversion?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Why `iWantInt(a)` does not compile while `iWantInt(b)` and - what is more surprising - `iWantInt` does ?

How can I understand this behaviour ?

Why can I not pass explicitly `a` to `iWantInt` when I can pass it implicitly ?

How is `iWantA` different from `iWantInt` ? Why does it not work the same way ?

Is this behavior documented/explained somewhere ?

If Scala would accept `iWantInt(a)` what kind of problems would that cause ? Why is it forbidden ?

```
class A

class B

object Run extends App {
  implicit val a = new A
  implicit val b = new B
  implicit def A2Int(implicit a:A)=1
  implicit def B2Int(b:B)=2
  def iWantA(implicit a:A)=println("A")
  def iWantInt(implicit i: Int) = println(i)

  iWantInt(b) // prints 2

  iWantInt    // prints 1
//  iWantInt(a) // when uncommented this line does not compile, why ?

  iWantA      // prints A
  iWantA(a)   // prints A
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of defining an implicit conversion, `A2Int` acts like a value that has been declared implicit, like `implicit val a` in the example, the only difference being that an implicit `A` must be discovered in scope for it to work. This is what allows `iWantInt` without an explicit parameter to compile - the compiler finds `A2Int` as the implicit `Int`, then finds `a` as the implicit `A` for `A2Int`.

For a function to qualify as an implicit conversion it must take a single non-implicit parameter. `B2Int` takes the single parameter `(b: B)` and so meets the requirement. This allows `iWantInt(b)` to compile. `A2Int` has `(implicit a: A)` but because this parameter is implicit `A2Int` does not meet the requirement and so `iWantInt(a)` does not compile, unless a line like `implicit def A2Int2(a:A) = 1` is added. If you run `scalac` with the `-feature` flag (which it will suggest at least with 2.11) it will display warnings for `B2Int` and `A2Int2`, saying that implicit conversions should be explicitly enabled by making visible `scala.language.implicitConversions`. It does not show the warning for `A2Int`, demonstrating that the compiler does not treat it as an implicit conversion.

The [Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) is the definitive definition for Scala. See Chapter 7, "Implicit Parameters and Views" for the specification of how these particular features behave.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Could you please clarify what do you mean by "An implicit conversion requires that there be a single non-implicit parameter." ? An implicit parameter where ?

Comment: So you mean that implicit def A2Int(implicit a:A) does not count as an implicit conversion because its parameter is implicit ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I've edited the second paragraph to make it clearer.

Comment: Many thanks ! I think it's time that I try to really understand the SLS.